# iPad connected to LG Ultrafine 4K Display

Tags: ios, ipad, display

The Apple support document for the LG Ultrafine 4K display states here that only newer Macs are supported.
https://support.apple.com/HT207447

I was wondering if it is possible to use a ***Lighting to USB 3.1 Type C*** cable to transfer video+audio to the LG display. This following entry for a specific cable on Amazon mentions:

```
also supports USB quick charging, and high performance video and audio transfer
```

[https://www.amazon.com/USB-3-1-Type-JOTO-White/dp/B01540Q4FK](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B01540Q4FK)

Has someone tested this and can someone confirm that this is (not) working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**No, it will only charge the iPad.**

Lightning doesn't have anything to do with HDMI. It's just a serial bus that cannot send any HDMI data without some help.

With Apple's Lightning Digital AV Adapter ([which, in fact, is just small computer itself](https://panic.com/blog/the-lightning-digital-av-adapter-surprise/)) you can output to an HDMI display. The native resolution is only 1600x900, however.