# iPad Pro to LG Ultrafine 4K

Tags: ipad, display, usb, hdmi

Using the Apple Lightning > HDMI display adapter and then an HDMI > USB-C adaptor, can I output my 9.7" iPad Pro to my LG Ultrafine 4K for word processing etc?

This [question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/270592/ipad-connected-to-lg-ultrafine-4k-display) implies that it could be done, albeit at a 1600x900 resolution. Has anyone tried this? Does the Ultrafine scale up the resolution satisfactorily?

Comment: I don't think this will work because I suspect all HDMI to USBC adapters are for hooking up an HDMI monitor or TV to a USBC computer, and they probably do not work in reverse. But if you used just the lightning to HDMI adapter and connected to an HDMI (or DVI) monitor, that should work just fine.

Answer (score 1):

According to [this article](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202044) at Apple.com it should be possible to hook up an external display to an iOS device.

The only question that remains is if hooking up a couple of adapters in series will actually work. If no one here knows from experience, I would buy the adapters from a store with a good return policy and have at it.